# Animate UIRectFill / Transparent Section of view

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I currently have a custom view with a transparent section in the section. I am currently creating that by using:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    bgColor.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let holeRect = imageView.frame
    let intersect = CGRectIntersection(holeRect, rect)
    UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
    UIRectFill(intersect)
}
```

I also would like to animate the inner view that is transparent, first it will get smaller and then animate the transparent section to be larger.... How would I go about making this happen?

I currently have this as my animations

```
func startAnimating(completion: () -> Void) {

    let shrinkDuration = animationDuration * 0.5
    let growDuration = animationDuration * 0.9
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(shrinkDuration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        //Do Animation
        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
        self.imageView.transform = scaleTransform
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.setNeedsDisplay()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(growDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
            let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(20, 20)
            self.imageView.transform = scaleTransform
            self.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
            completion()
        })

    }
}
```

This doesnt resize the holeRect section though

Comment: You are animating alpha of self, do you want to animate the alpha of self or the imageView? Who is self in this case?

Comment: self is just a subclass of UIView. The view should have a red background, and in the center, where the imageView is, should be transparent and besides the image, you should be able to see the superview.

I am first changing the size of the imageView/ transparent rect and then I am fading and removing the entire view @IcaroNZ

Comment: in that case try to use: self.backgroundColor = UIColor.<yourColor>.colorWithAlphaComponent(0) instead self.alpha

Comment: @IcaroNZ i think there;s a misunderstanding. I am able to get the fading of the view to work, but what I can't seem to animate is the resizing of the "holeRect" section

Comment: Sorry I am confuse now, in your animations you are animating just the imageView not the UIView

Comment: @IcaroNZ i would like to animate the holeRect along with the imageView

Comment: You cannot animate the holeRect as it is a local variable, you can move the holeRect to be a global variable and animate it, or, you can animate the hole view using self.transform = scaleTransform inside your animation block

Answer (score 0):

Try Add the following animation block

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    //animate your alpha property here
}, completion: { finished in
    //do whatever you need to do when the animation finish 
})
```